# Добавить поддержку .fb2 в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Собственно говоря как добавить поддержку формата .fb2 я пробовал добавить вот такой код в functions.php

```
//загрузка новых типов медиафайлов start
function wph_add_mime_types($mimes) {
$mimes['fb2'] = 'application/xml';
//$mimes['fb2'] = 'text/xml';
//$mimes['fb2'] = 'application/x-fictionbook+xml';
return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'wph_add_mime_types');
//загрузка новых типов медиафайлов end
```

но выдаёт ошибку «Извините, этот тип файла недопустим по соображениям безопасности».Я не знаю какой тип mime у формата fb2 это не указано на вики и я предположил что это просто формат xml но это неверно насколько я понимаю.

Comment: попробуйте `application/msword`

Comment: @Алексей не помогло :(

Comment: тогда можете добавить через плагин `WP Add Mime Types`, скорей всего WP не может определить расширение файла при загрузке. Лично я бы просто архивировал в zip и загружал его.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить следующий код:

```
function wph_add_mime_types($mimes) {
    $mimes['fb2'] = 'application/x-fictionbook';
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'wph_add_mime_types');
```

Comment: Увы не заработало(

Answer (score 0):

`$mimes['fb2'] = 'text/xml';` будет работать,проверил